# Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function consistent-return

Tags: javascript, express, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.task) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: "Task Can't be empty",
    });
  }
  const task = new Task({
    task: req.body.task,
  });
  task.save()
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || 'Some error occurred while creating the Task.',
      });
    });
};
```

This is my function and I tried different ways of putting return but O still get the error:

> Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function consistent-return
> on 1:29.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: I don't know what your problem, but maybe you can try add return before res.send & res.status. Look at the third line, in there, you add return res.status(400). Maybe you should to do to another res.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return` to your task.save()'s `then` and `catch` arrow functions too like this:

```
task.save().then((data) => {
  return res.send(data);
})
.catch((err) => {
  return res.status(500).send({
    message: err.message || 'Some error occurred while creating the Task.',
  });
});
```

Comment: I was able to do it and yes it is correct though i did it before but it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `create` function needs to return a specific value, so make sure that the only `return` you have in there, is without value.

Change:

```
return res.status(400).send({
  message: "Task Can't be empty",
});
```

to:

```
res.status(400).send({
  message: "Task Can't be empty",
});
return;
```